# ASP Core 3.1 redirect unauthorised user to custom page

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have published my first ASP Core 3.1 MVC web app in Azure and now I have to control access as we have around 2300 AD users (staff/students). I have created a user group in Azure AD and turned on 'User Assignment' for my App. I have assigned the user group to my app. So far, I am the only person in this group and I can log in and navigate the web app. If I log in with a different user account NOT in this group a raw style Access Denied message is displayed ('access denied', error description: 'AADSTS50105, etc.). This process works as expected but I would like to provide a non-tech custom page which explains to the user why they have been denied access to the site and what to do to gain access.

I'm not sure how to go about replacing this page, and would appreciate some advice.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
        .Build();

        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => config.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        services.AddControllers();
       
    }
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UseStatusCodePages` middleware to handle the HTTP error. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#usestatuscodepages-with-lambda-1)

There are a few overloads available, for example `UseStatusCodePages` with a lambda in which you can handle the different codes.

An example from the docs:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

    await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
        "Status code page, status code: " + 
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
});
```

There are also extension methods available. Note that `UseStatusCodePages` should be called before request handling middleware (for example, Static File Middleware and MVC Middleware).